# Postgres in recovery mode after failed delete queries from partitioned table (PG 12)

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I have a code that used to work on a simple table and **stopped working when the same table was partitioned to many sub-partitioned.**

In a **distributed application (Spark) we have code that performs batch delete queries in parallel from different computers in the same time (deleting different records).**

Most of the queries work but then one of them fails on what seems to be a socket connection
timeout:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 DELETE FROM my_table WHERE vessel_id='xxxxxx' AND day='2020-09-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp was aborted: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)

When the code retries to run the task the connection fails on 
:FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

In the database log I see:

```
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC::@:[26848]:DETAIL:  Failed process was running: DELETE FROM my_table WHERE vessel_id=$1 AND day=$2
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC::@:[26848]:LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:172.31.4.110(59468):postgres@postgres:[27705]:WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:172.31.4.110(59468):postgres@postgres:[27705]:DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:172.31.4.110(59468):postgres@postgres:[27705]:HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:10.3.1.138(57926):rdsrepladmin@[unknown]:[26740]:WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:10.3.1.138(57926):rdsrepladmin@[unknown]:[26740]:DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:10.3.1.138(57926):rdsrepladmin@[unknown]:[26740]:HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC::@:[22480]:WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC::@:[22480]:DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC::@:[22480]:HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-09-21 16:44:27 UTC:127.0.0.1(31826):rdsadmin@rdsadmin:[27967]:FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

Any ideas why the database fails when the table is partitioned?
Why all the other connections on the other computers are closed and the database goes into recovery mode?

Comment: Why it happens should be stated in the log file, just before the point where you started quoting.

Comment: I have few tests:

2020-09-21 16:26:53 UTC::@:[26848]:LOG:  server process (PID 5509) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2020-09-21 16:26:53 UTC::@:[26848]:DETAIL:  Failed process was running: DELETE..


2020-09-21 16:33:18 UTC::@:[9289]:WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2020-09-21 16:33:18 UTC::@:[15641]:WARNING:  autovacuum worker started without a worker entry
2020-09-21 16:34:22 UTC::@:[26848]:LOG:  server process (PID 12961) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2020-09-21 16:34:22 UTC::@:[26848]:DETAIL:  Failed process was running: DELETE...

Comment: Something is killing your database server with signal 9.  It is likely the out of memory killer, see the system log file (something like /var/log/syslog) to see if there are details about it.  If you are on MacOS, it could also be the code-signing feature interacting with JIT.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the logs I found that the problem was out-of-memory.
This database instance is the main instance, it does the writing, replicating and deleting and it didn't have enough memory to handle all these tasks at the same time.

The fix was simply to add more memory.
Nothing fancy.